# Reporting Seccomp violations

Tags: ubuntu, syslog, audit

When running seccomp-constrained processes, I would like to see any seccomp violations in some logs. Some googling online shows that these violations are reported to either syslog or audit.log. However, I am not seeing them there even though I know of processes dying due to them. Is this something that needs enabling somewhere?

I am using Ubuntu Xenial 16.04.

EDIT: I found that `SCMP_ACT_ERRNO`, the flag that I was using, does not trigger logging. It is only `SCMP_ACT_KILL` that triggers the logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points:

- you should have installed the auditing daemon package, `auditd`.
- in its default configuration `auditd` doesn't do much except record when users log-in.

Either way, you'll have to *configure* it to make it useful.

Further reading:

- [auditd - The Linux Audit daemon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/auditd.8.html)
- [Simple example auditd configuration?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4629/simple-example-auditd-configuration)
- [Auditd - Tool for Security Auditing on Linux Server](http://linoxide.com/how-tos/auditd-tool-security-auditing/)
- [Configuring and auditing Linux systems with Audit daemon](https://linux-audit.com/configuring-and-auditing-linux-systems-with-audit-daemon/)

The manual page doesn't doesn't go very deep, which is why I pointed to the additional pages.

There is not much available for reading about configuring seccomp itself.  Here are some useful starting points (which include comments that auditd may not need configuration because seccomp is reported unconditionally):

- [Seccomp and sandboxing](http://lwn.net/Articles/332974/)
- [Re: [PATCH] Don't audit SECCOMP_KILL/RET_ERRNO when syscall auditing is disabled](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/4/10/658)
- [seccomp and audit_enabled](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2015-October/msg00039.html)

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to to configure auditd to report seccomp violations? I went through the auditd.conf and auditctl man pages and there is nothing about seccomp.

Comment: I've downvoted this answers because it essentially doesn't answer the question. I've installed `auditd` and have yet to figure out how to get it to log seccomp violations.